# Tsql query for periods by buy / sell?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

An agent buys products from factory and sells them to normal people.

e.g.

he buy **apple** ( buy) (1/1/2010)

next day he buys again **apple** ( buy)  (2/1/2010)

later he buys **orange** ( buy)  (2/1/2010)

later he sells **apple** ( sell)  (3/1/2010)

later he sells **apple** ( sell)  (20/1/2010)

<=**here** the cycle of buy/sell for **apple** has finished.

sells the **orange**         (22/1/2010)

i need Query result that tells me for each cycle - this :>

```
item  |   numberOfItems |   timeFromBeginingToVanish
------------------------------------------------------
apple             2                    19 days                   // ( 20/1 - 1/1)
orange            1                     20 days                   //(22/1 - 2/1)
```

notice :

he can buy another apple and not to sell him - this WONT be in the list.

**only when the stack is FIRST TO BE FINISHED**

Comment: *‘this WONT be in the list’* – what exactly won't be in the list, the third apple or the entire `apple` row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I have added another filter (`HAVING` clause) to display only those cycles that are `completed` .

This solution uses recursive CTE:

1) to compute a running total (RunningTotal) for every item and

2) to generate a group id (PseudoDenseRank) for every item cycle.

```
CREATE TABLE [Transaction]
(
     TransactionId INT IDENTITY(10,10) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Item   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,TransactionType CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
    ,Qty    INT NOT NULL
    ,TransactionDate DATE NOT NULL
    ,CHECK( TransactionType IN ('B', 'S') ) --Buy, Sell
);

INSERT  [Transaction]
SELECT  'apple', 'B', 1, '2010-01-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'apple', 'B', 1, '2010-01-02'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'orange','B', 1, '2010-01-03'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'apple', 'S', 1, '2010-01-03'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'apple', 'S', 1, '2010-01-20'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'orange','S', 1, '2010-01-22'

UNION ALL
SELECT  'apple', 'B', 2, '2010-02-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'orange','B', 3, '2010-02-02'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'apple', 'S', 1, '2010-02-03'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'apple', 'S', 1, '2010-02-10'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'orange','S', 1, '2010-02-10'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'orange','S', 1, '2010-02-11';

DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
     TransactionId INT NOT NULL
    ,Item   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,TransactionType CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
    ,Qty    INT NOT NULL
    ,TransactionDate DATE NOT NULL
    ,RowNum INT NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (Item, RowNum)
);

INSERT  @Results 
SELECT  *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Item ORDER BY t.TransactionDate ASC, t.TransactionType ASC, t.TransactionId ASC) RowNum
FROM    [Transaction] t;

WITH CteRecursive
AS
(
    SELECT  q.Item
            ,q.RowNum
            ,CASE WHEN q.TransactionType = 'B' THEN q.Qty END QtyBuy
            ,CASE WHEN q.TransactionType = 'S' THEN q.Qty END QtySell
            ,q.TransactionDate
            ,CASE WHEN q.TransactionType = 'B' THEN q.Qty WHEN q.TransactionType = 'S' THEN -q.Qty END AS RunningTotal
            ,1 AS PseudoDenseRank
    FROM    @Results q
    WHERE   q.RowNum = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  prev.Item
            ,crt.RowNum
            ,CASE WHEN crt.TransactionType = 'B' THEN crt.Qty END QtyBuy
            ,CASE WHEN crt.TransactionType = 'S' THEN crt.Qty END QtySell
            ,crt.TransactionDate
            ,prev.RunningTotal + CASE WHEN crt.TransactionType = 'B' THEN crt.Qty WHEN crt.TransactionType = 'S' THEN -crt.Qty END
            ,CASE WHEN prev.RunningTotal = 0 THEN prev.PseudoDenseRank + 1 ELSE prev.PseudoDenseRank END
    FROM    CteRecursive prev
    INNER JOIN @Results crt ON prev.Item = crt.Item
    AND     prev.RowNum + 1 = crt.RowNum 
)
SELECT   q.Item
        ,q.PseudoDenseRank      AS CycleNumber
        ,SUM(q.QtyBuy)          AS QtyBuyTotal
        ,SUM(q.QtySell)         AS QtySellTotal
        ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(SUM(q.QtyBuy), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(q.QtySell),0) = 0 THEN 'Complete' ELSE 'Incomplete' END AS CycleStatus
        ,MIN(q.TransactionDate) AS CycleStartDate
        ,MAX(q.TransactionDate) AS CycleEndDate 
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), MIN(q.TransactionDate), 112) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), MAX(q.TransactionDate), 112) AS CycleInterval
FROM    CteRecursive q
GROUP BY q.Item, q.PseudoDenseRank
HAVING   ISNULL(SUM(q.QtyBuy), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(q.QtySell),0) = 0
ORDER BY q.Item, q.PseudoDenseRank;

DROP TABLE [Transaction];
```

Results:

```
Item   CycleNumber QtyBuyTotal QtySellTotal CycleStatus CycleStartDate CycleEndDate CycleInterval
------ ----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- -------------- ------------ -----------------------
apple  1           2           2            Complete    2010-01-01     2010-01-20   2010-01-01 - 2010-01-20
apple  2           2           2            Complete    2010-02-01     2010-02-10   2010-02-01 - 2010-02-10
orange 1           1           1            Complete    2010-01-03     2010-01-22   2010-01-03 - 2010-01-22
--The next row is eliminated by the filter from HAVING
orange 2           3           2            Incomplete  2010-02-02     2010-02-11   2010-02-02 - 2010-02-11
```

Comment: If there were 3 rows `'apple', 'B', 1` and 2 rows `'apple', 'S', 1` all having the same cycle number, this solution would filter out the entire cycle. However, in an answer to my question about such a case, the OP answered that only the third `'B'` item should be filtered out. (My understanding is, the third item should just be ignored as if it did not exist.)

Comment: @Andriy M , If there were 3 rows 'apple', 'B', 1 and 2 rows 'apple', 'S', 1 all having the same cycle number, this solution would filter out the entire cycle. : correct. let me clarify : if he +1+1 and then -1-1 and then +1 : so we have a cycle which began with 2 apples and he sold them ( stack pointer is 0)  - this i want to see in the query. but later he only bought an apple ( without selling it) so he started a cycle but didn't completed it - so this line of apple wont be considered  in the query results.

Comment: Andriy M - did you tested my solution with or without HAVING clause ? From my point of view, 3 ('apple' 'B' 1) rows and 2 ('apple' 'S' 1) rows mean an incomplete cycle. These cycle is eliminated by the filter from HAVING clause. If you comment or remove HAVING clause you will get all cycles regardless cycle status.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: I did test it. It was my interpretation of Royi Namir's answer that was incorrect. I've made a couple more tests now, and it appears that your solution actually works as expected. Good job!

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Seems like I was somewhat careless when reading your original post. Everything is clear now, thanks for taking your time to clarify things to me!

Comment: Royi Namir - I don't know what constraints (CHECKs, TRIGGERs) are defined in your database or at application level (C#,VB.NET, etc.) but to prevent getting wrong results, some constraints are needed to prevent the scenarios when selling quantity is bigger than previous purchased quantity. Example: 3 ('apple' 'B' 1) rows and then 4 ('apple' 'S' 1) rows => 3-4=stock -1 or 1 ('apple' 'B'  Qty=1) row and then 2 ('apple' 'S' 1) rows => 1-2 = stock -1.

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean you cant sell what you didnt buy

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Hi Can i redirect you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142342/sql-server-solve-this-with-set-based-solution-instead-of-row-iteration/8142407#8142407 ??