# SQL Server - Solve this with set-based solution instead of row iteration

Tags: sql-server, cursor, set, loops

I'm trying to move some of my business logic out of my programs and into stored procedures. I'm really a VB.NET programmer, and not a SQL expert, but I'm learning more SQL and finding that in a lot of cases, it's faster to let SQL do my processing and return small amounts of data rather than giving me a ton of stuff and having my programs chomp through it.

So, my current problem is this:

I'm creating a timeline of something that has occurred from several different sources in a database. The pertinent information I am pulling is:

1. A user name
2. A time associated with an action

I want to use this timeline to figure out, ultimately, who was responsible for a given thing at a given time. Thus, if 1 user logs 400 actions in a row before a new user logs something, I really don't care; I just want to see when user 1 started logging and when user 2 took over logging.

More graphical example:

### User    |         Time

User1   |              12:00
User1   |              12:01
User1   |              12:02
User1   |              12:03
User1   |              12:04
User1   |              12:05
User1   |              12:06
User2   |              12:07
User2   |              12:08
User2   |              12:09
User2   |              12:10
User2   |              12:11
User1   |              12:12
User1   |              12:13

What I'd like:

### User             Time

User1   |              12:00
User2   |              12:07
User1   |              12:12

Now, in code, I'd get that result set into a DataTable and iterate each row in the table. Then, I'd check the current row's [User Name] value against the previous row's [User Name] value and only add the current row's values if the [User Name] was different. There seems to be a general aversion among true SQL experts to using a cursor, but I'm not sure I yet think in that manner, so can anyone help me out here?

So far, I have successfully gotten the raw, unfiltered data into a table variable in my query. So, I just need to know how to "collapse" the data and only return a small subset.

Thanks!

Comment: I created  the right solution. see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>**EDIT** Needs 1 more level of indirection for filtering by rank to work:</s>

```
select 
  User,Time
from
(
  select *
  from
  (
      Select 
        User,Time, rank() over (partition by u.User order by u.Time) as User_Rank
      from 
        your_table u
  ) UserRanks
) x
where User_Rank = 1
order by Time
```

Similar to araqnid and Royi's answers, but using WHERE NOT EXISTS rather than JOIN.

```
with CTE  as (
    select user, time, row_number() over (order by time) rn from MyTable
)  
select    CTE.user, CTE.time
from CTE CTE1
where not exists (select user, time from CTE CTE2 where CTE1.rn = CTE2.rn - 1 and CTE1.user = CTE2.user)
```

Comment: Here's what is working: Select Staff, [Time] 
From (Select Staff, [Time], row_number() Over (Partition By Staff Order By [Time]) As rowNum From @Temp) aa
Where rowNum = 1
Order By [Time]

Comment: @mbm30075 you are **wrong** this query is not working properly. (for what youve asked....it will never bring you the last user1 in `user1...user2...user1`)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Actually, I'm looking for the **first** in each block, so the code I posted above works beautifully for me.

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, I mean the code I posted in my comment above (comment on 11/15 @ 20:25).

Answer (score 0):

### Finally :

```
;with CTE  as (
    select user, time, row_number() over (order by time) rn from MyTable
)  
select    CTE.user, CTE.time
from CTE left join CTE other on other.rn = CTE .rn - 1
where other.user is null or CTE .user <> other.user
```

Answer (score 0):

A row-based iteration is probably your best solution in SQL Server. Other database flavours allow you to example values from the previous/next row (`lag` and `lead` window functions), but SQL Server doesn't support those.

You could bodge something together like this:

```
with x as (
    select user, time, row_number() over (order by time) rn from source
)
select x.user, x.time
from x left join x prev on prev.rn = x.rn - 1
where prev.user is null or x.user <> prev.user
```

However, I suspect this is inconvenient and performs abominably.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those exceptions where a cursor is likely your best bet.  Just try to limit the subset of data that you are going to iterate as much as you can.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my OP, but the PARTITION keyword really gets me exactly what I want.